# C++ variable address does not match

Tags: c++

```
class CCtrl
{
    ...Other Members...
    RankCache m_stRankCache;
    uint32 m_uSyncListTime;
};

int CCtrl::UpdateList()
{
    uint32 tNow = GetNowTime();

    for (uint8 i = 0; i < uRankListNum; i++)
    {
        m_stRankCache.Append(i);
    }

    m_uSyncListTime = tNow;
    return 0;
}
```

Here are two weired things:

1. When step into Append(), p this = 0x7f3f467edfdc, but in UpdateGuildList(), p &m_stRankCache = 0x7f3f067edfdc, these two pointers are different.
2. tNow = 1418916316, after executing m_uSyncListTime = tNow, m_uSyncListTime is still 0.

How could this happen? I've used a whole day for debugging. And I checked my code there is no pack(1) and pack() mismatch.

Comment: could you show in your code exactly which pointers you are talking about? I am a bit confused - probably because we don't have the whole code.

Comment: how and where do you allocate m_stRankCache?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? Debuggers have a tendency of giving incorrect results when used with an optimized build.

Comment: @hagubear in RankCache::Append(), pointer of this is 0x7f3f467edfdc, in CCtrl::UpdateList(), pointer of m_stRankCache is 0x7f3f067edfdc, the difference is 0x000040000000.

Comment: @ComicSansMS The project is a very mature code base. I only added some new features. optimization flag is -O3 and I didn't change it.

Comment: @pixar And how are you detecting that the pointers are different?  If it's the debugger and you have optimizations turned on, then that may explain the issue.

Comment: @rokjarc RankCache is a class with 2 members: DataType m_astData[MAX_ARRAY_LEN] and uint32 m_uLength

Comment: @pixar That's most likely your problem. Could you try recompiling with `-O0` and check whether the problems still occur? Note that this is not a failure of your code, just a general problem of debuggers being unable to properly inspect optimized builds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I use gdb step by step to trace the variables and find m_uSyncListTime does not be modified to new value.

Comment: @pixar As your last comment suggested, you are using optimizations.  Therefore take what the debugger is giving you with a grain of salt.  Recompile with no optimizations and debug.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, built with -O0 does not work, the problem is still there.

Comment: p tNow 1418919280, 
p &m_uSyncListTime 0x7fe84c040ad8, 
p *(SSGame::uint32 *) 0x7fe84c040ad8 is 0
p*(SSGame::uint32 *) 0x7fe88c040ad8 is the correct value 1418919280

It seems the address of m_uSyncListTime has an offset of 0x000040000000.

Comment: @pixar - A simple question - Does your program work?  If so, then I still claim it is a debugger issue.  Why not do a simple `cout` of these variables instead of the debugger?  If you still get that the pointers are not the same, either you're using some sort of multiple inheritance thing going on that you're not showing us, or you've got a corrupted/inconsistent build, or you've totally clobbered memory somewhere...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, You are right. It works. I dump the m_uSyncListTime value to log file and it is the correct value. Thank you very much. gdb is so buggy here.

Comment: @pixar - Debuggers have their flaws in rare cases.  In this case you have to do your own detective work to figure out the actual values, and that required just "old school" methods of logging and outputting the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is more than likely that you're using your debugger to debug code that has been optimized.  As your comment suggested, you are debugging code that has been compiled with the `-O3` flag, denoting optimization.

Even though you're using `gdb`, the Visual Studio and other debuggers also have the same issue, and that issue is debugging optimized code and having the debugger "work" in the sense that the debugger follows along with the lines in the source code, along with the variables that have been declared.

A debugger assumes that the lines of the source code match up with the generated assembly code.  With optimizations turned on, this can no longer be the case.  Code and variables are eliminated, moved, etc.  Therefore the lines in the code (including variable declarations) you believe should be there at a certain location may not be there in the final optimized build.

The debugger cannot discern these changes, thus you get erroneous values used for variables, or in some cases, you get "variable doesn't exist" errors reported by your debugger.

Also, it may also serve as a good check to do a simple `cout` or log of the values in question if there is a problem with the debugging environment.  There are situations where even debuggers may get things wrong, so a backup verification system (i.e. logging, printf() or `cout` statements, etc.) should be used.